# A website can directly get the location of every electrode of 10-20 system

Tags: neuroscience, eeg

There is a website about the eeg 10-20 system.
When I input the circle of the head and the distance between the inion and nasion, I can directly get the location of every point from Cz or else.
But I can't find it. I probably remeber the domain is start with `eeg.clinical...`, so anyone have used it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is helpful, but you could use a toolbox like EEGLAB that has these files for you ([see this tutorial](https://eeglab.org/tutorials/04_Import/Channel_Locations.html))